# python list and dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary

This is my jail, with M for Male department and F for female department:

```
prison = {'M': {1: {'prisonniers': [], 'sécurité': 90}, 2: {'prisonniers': [], 'sécurité': 55}, 3: {'prisonniers': [], 'sécurité': 17}}, 'F': {1: {'prisonniers': [1], 'sécurité': 60}, 2: {'prisonniers': [], 'sécurité': 36}}, 'taille': 6}
```

I have an another txt file with captives like this one:

```
{'F': [{'nom': 'Wanda Maximoff', 'crimes': ['A conspiré avec Ultron', 'A agressé Vision', "A détruit l'aéroport de Vienne"], 'univers': 'Marvel', 'ID': 501988, 'danger': 45}], 'M': [{'nom': 'Le Joker', 'crimes': ['Meurtre', 'Braquage de banques', 'Mauvaises blagues'], 'univers': 'DC', 'ID': 48235, 'danger': 87}]
```

Now I need to put these captives inside my jail but I need to respect that the level of security of the division must be higher or equal to the level of danger

So I've tried to take captives one by one, to verify which division they can go, and I made a list with all the division

```
list_of_division = [{'prisonniers': [], 'sécurité': '47'}, {'prisonniers': [], 'sécurité': '92'}, {'prisonniers': [], 'sécurité': '38'}]
```

Then I took the lowest value with:

```
value = min(list_of_division, key= lambda elem: elem['sécurité'])
```

But now I need to search inside dict prison and fill in the captive inside it.

Thanks.

Comment: You haven't asked a question.

Comment: Expected output?

Comment: i search how to fill in my dictionnary prison

Comment: How do you want to fill it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is that you loop over the captives and assign each one to a prison that has a sécurité equal to or above their danger and then to keep costs down they are assigned to the prison that has the least sécurité.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

prisons = {'M': {1: {'prisonniers': [], 'sécurité': 90}, 2: {'prisonniers': [], 'sécurité': 55}, 3: {'prisonniers': [], 'sécurité': 17}}, 'F': {1: {'prisonniers': [], 'sécurité': 60}, 2: {'prisonniers': [], 'sécurité': 36}}, 'taille': 6}
captives = {'F': [{'nom': 'Wanda Maximoff', 'crimes': ['A conspiré avec Ultron', 'A agressé Vision', "A détruit l'aéroport de Vienne"], 'univers': 'Marvel', 'ID': 501988, 'danger': 45}], 'M': [{'nom': 'Le Joker', 'crimes': ['Meurtre', 'Braquage de banques', 'Mauvaises blagues'], 'univers': 'DC', 'ID': 48235, 'danger': 87}]}

for gender, captives in captives.items():
    for captive in captives:
        jails = filter(lambda elem: elem['sécurité'] >= captive['danger'], 
                       prisons[gender].values())
        if not jails:
            print("No prison can hold:", captive['nom'])
            continue

        jail = min(jails, key=lambda elem: elem['sécurité'])
        jail['prisonniers'].append(captive)

print(prisons)
```

Prints:

```
{'taille': 6, 'M': {1: {'prisonniers': [{'univers': 'DC', 'nom': 'Le Joker', 'crimes': ['Meurtre', 'Braquage de banques', 'Mauvaises blagues'], 'ID': 48235, 'danger': 87}], 'sécurité': 90}, 2: {'prisonniers': [], 'sécurité': 55}, 3: {'prisonniers': [], 'sécurité': 17}}, 'F': {1: {'prisonniers': [{'univers': 'Marvel', 'nom': 'Wanda Maximoff', 'crimes': ['A conspiré avec Ultron', 'A agressé Vision', "A détruit l'aéroport de Vienne"], 'ID': 501988, 'danger': 45}], 'sécurité': 60}, 2: {'prisonniers': [], 'sécurité': 36}}}
```

That is Le Joker with danger 87 got assigned to M1 prison with sécurité 90. And Wanda Maximoff with danger 45 got assigned to F1 prison with sécurité 60.